# Mandrill base64 inline image in format of image/svg+xml is not visible in email?

Tags: javascript, json, api, mandrill, email-templates

When I send emails using Mandrill with images that are encoded in ***image/svg+xml*** format them are not visible in email.

`

> "images": [{
>
> "type": "image/xml+svg",
>
> "name": "S1",
>
> "content":PHN2ZyB4bWxuczp4bGluaz0iaHR0cDovL3d3......
>
> }]

` Images are displayed well on web-page if I render them  as

> ```
> <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2Z......>
> ```

Also Mandrill works fine and shows images if I use ***image/png*** and use base64 encoded string for image

Comment: email clients can not handle base64 encoded images, tried it once too

Comment: It is not true:) Them handle it good enough.
Also I'm talking about Mandrill email provider. It uses different way - not just include images src inline, but adds images to attachments and then uses urls to attachments

Answer (score 0):

SVG images in emails are problematic. Your code is good but email clients just do not display SVG images (e.g. iPhone native email client does but GMail, Hotmail, Yahoo, ... don't). See this online test which shows which email clients do/don't display SVG images: http://conference.createsend.com/screens/r/06A83737A07C505E?_ga=1.195278186.717901520.1441198800